# Creating my own function to integrate by the trapezoidal rule

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction

I'm trying to write a custom function that takes a definite integral and approximates the value using the trapezoidal rule. As can be seen in the code below, I first did this by defining all the variables separately:

```
f[x_] = 2 x^3;
a = 0;
b = 1;
n = 2;
Δx = (b - a)/n;
x[i_] = a + i*Δx;
Sum[(f[a] + 2 f[x[i]] + f[b])*.5 Δx, {i, 1, n - 1}];
```

Then, I tried putting all of this into a single function. Substituting out `f[x[i]]` and Deltax for what it is they represent:

```
Tn[f_, a_, b_, n_] := 
  Sum[(f[a] + 2 f[a + i ((b - a)/n)] + f[b])*.5 ((b - a)/n), {i, 1, n - 1}]
```

I got this to work with the function I first tested, `2 x^3` at 2 intervals, but the results for other tests I did were vastly overestimated, so clearly that was just dumb luck and I have an issue in my code somewhere. Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your trapezoidal sum is simply wrong; compare carefully with, e.g., [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Uniform_grid).

Your formulation is

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{b-a}{2n}\left[f(a)+2f\left(a+\frac{i(b-a)}{n}\right)+f(b)\right]$$

where $\frac{b-a}{2n}$ can be taken out of the sum as it doesn't contain the iterator $i$. Note that then $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are summed $(n-1)$ times, so the $sum\,of\,2\,f(...)$ is increased by $(n-1)[f(a)+f(b)]$, hence the overestimation.

The correct form is

$$\frac{b-a}{2n}\left[f(a)+f(b)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}2f\left(a+\frac{i(b-a)}{n}\right) \right]$$

where you don't take $(n-1)$ times $f(a)+f(b)$, but only once:

```
Tn[f_, a_, b_, n_] := 0.5*((b - a)/n)*
     (f[a] + f[b] + Sum[2*f[a + (i*(b - a))/n], {i, 1, n - 1}])
```

gives

```
Tn[2 #^3 &, 0, 1, 20]
```

> 0.50125

Compare with exact result:

```
Integrate[2 x^3, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> 1/2

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting 2.5 instead of the expected estimation of .625 with two intervals

`Tn[f_, a_, b_, n_] := ((b - a)/2 n)*(f[a] + f[b] +Sum[2 f[a + ((i (b - a))/n)], {i, 1, n - 1}])`

Comment: Because `1/2 n` is `0.5 n`; should be `1/(2 n)`.

Comment: Substituting ((b-a)/(2n)) for ((b-a)/2n) nets the sameresult, I don't believe it is that.

Comment: The correct `Tn` is provided in my answer. `Tn[2 #^3 &, 0, 1, 2]` yields `0.625`. Correcting your `2 n` to `(2 n)` gives the same result. I don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: Hard-resetting the notebook seems to have done it, nevermind. Thank you for the assistance.